# Requests Dialog box popup issue

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am using FB request dialog box in my PHP script. It is working in all browsers except in Safari. In fact there is problem with popup blocker option. Most of modern browsers are blocking popups and this option is also enabled in safari by default. It is little challenging for me to bypass popup blocker and make functional FB request dialog box. However it is also not make sense that I should request to website user for uncheck popup blocker option in their browser before to use my application. The code is below :

```
            FB.ui({
            method: "apprequests",
             to:''+str+'',           
          message: "xxxxxxxxxx",
          name: "xxxxxxx",
          description: "",
          data: JSON.stringify({code:key,usr:uid,vi:'vi',invt:'invt'}), 
          picture: "<?php echo $fb_image;?>",
          link: link_url,
          display: 'popup'
      }, function(response) {
          //------------------------------
      }




            FB init:
           <script type="text/javascript">
             FB.init({
             appId  : 'oauth_fb_key',
             status : true,
             cookie : true,
             oauth  : true,
             xfbml  : true
            });
           </script>
```

Is it control by above JS function which make call for request dialog box.

Comment: can you put your fb.init code here.

Comment: @Jay Hardia : Thanks for your reply. I also added fb.init code as you suggeted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting `display` parameter for `FB.ui`, like [described in doc](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.ui/). Try one of `iframe` or `page` options.

Comment: Thanks, your reply worth for me.

Comment: It worked when I replaced display: 'popup'   with display: 'iframe'. Now I have not any threat from browser's popup blocker.

Answer (score 1):

Put `frictionlessRequests : true` in your FB.init  & Fb.ui method's  'to' should be like

```
to:'comma separated facebook user id'
```

For reference : [Requests Dialog Facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/)